# Jquery return JSON object in a function

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a rowcount with JSON and get an output like this in my php file `json_data2.php`:

```
{"limit": [{"rows":"127"}]}
```

Now I'm calling this file using a Javascript/Jquery function and try to get the rows back (127). I pretend to do it like this:

```
function limit(keyword){
        $.getJSON("json_data2.php?l="+keyword,function(data)
        {
            $.each(data.limit,function(data){
                var rows = data.rows;
                return rows;
            });
        });
    }
```

But every time I call the function in the Script I get "undefined". Any pointers?

Comment: *Where* do you get "undefined"?

Comment: when I call the function

Comment: I mean what line above returns `undefined`?  Do you get an error?  Or does it have to do with what is displayed?  What happens when you go to `json_data2.php?l=` in a web browser?

Comment: @ExplosionPills OP gets undefined because `limit()` returns it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your each statement. Added `this` to refer to data in question.

http://jsfiddle.net/twGQh/

```
limit(keyword, function(rows) {
    // your rows have loaded
});

  function limit(keyword, cb){
            $.getJSON("json_data2.php?l="+keyword,function(data)
            {

                $.each(data.limit,function(){
                    var rows = this.rows;
                    console.log(rows);
                    cb(rows);
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Now I see 127 in the console, but the Variable of the function is still "undefined"

Comment: Conole shows 1 time 127 ,... from the function and one time undefined from the call ... still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your function limit(keyword) does not return any value.

An existing return operator returns value in the callback function of `$.each`

You have to add return operator in the body of your limit function.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous and therefore calling `limit()` will not return anything (useful).

The way to do this is by providing a callback function to `limit()` like:

```
limit(keyword, function(rows) {
    // your rows have loaded
    $.each(rows, function() {
        // process each row here
    });
});

function limit(keyword, cb)
{
    $.getJSON('json_data2.php?l=' + encodeURIComponent(keyword), function(data) {
        // invoke the callback function that was passed
        cb(data.limit);
    });
}
```